# Commerce product variations switching

Tags: 7, commerce

I have setup a product which has multiple variations as the image shows:

[image]

My variations have a colour taxonomy which I'm trying to use for when a user wishes to switch between variations on the same product.

**My problem is the product node is not presenting any option for selecting the list of available colour nor is there an add to cart form.**

I'm sure I'm missing one or two things ... I could use a second opinion, please.

**UPDATE:**

I already had the "**Enable this field to function as an attribute field on Add to Cart forms**" selected but didn't work.

I noticed in step#2 of the answer you directed me to, the taxonomy field is created in a Variation entity type.
However, I don't see a Variation entity listed on my site.
**I'm adding my colour taxonomy field into the product type entity as shown in the image below**:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the taxonomy field to be used as attributes so it is exposed to the cart form.

[image]

Here you've got the step by step guide here: https://drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/adding-taxonomy-field-product-attributes

Comment: thanks for your response. I already had that option selected to no effect. I updated my question with a more thorough answer. I would appreciate more of your help. Thanks